# vanillajs-datepicker get date on click (change)

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I'm trying to get a date when I click on a calendar date (change). The doc says there is a event trigger. But can't get it to work. I made a custom Event Listener 'click' however that's triggering the whole calendar.

*All Datepicker-event objects are CustomEvent instances and dispatched to the associated  element (for inline picker, the block element).*

```
const elem = document.querySelector('#kalenderdatum');
const datepicker = new Datepicker(elem, {
  calendarWeeks: true,
  todayHighlight: true
});

elem.addEventListener('click', function(){
   console.log('test');
   console.log(datepicker.getDate());
 });
```

https://mymth.github.io/vanillajs-datepicker/#/api?id=datepicker

Can someone please help how to use the customevent trigger.

Comment: 1/2 … Has the OP read the [API doc to DatePicker events](https://mymth.github.io/vanillajs-datepicker/#/api?id=events)? There it is stated that ... *"All Datepicker-event objects are [`CustomEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent) instances and dispatched to the associated <input> element"*. Furthermore the event names are listed, 4 `'change*'` events and `'show'`/`'hide'`. It also says that the data (4 properties) the OP might be interested in is part of `event.detail` of the `event` objects which is passed into the event handler (callback function).

Comment: 2/2 ... Thus the registry process for e.g. a [`'changeDate'`](https://mymth.github.io/vanillajs-datepicker/#/api?id=changedate) event for the OP's `elem` with an anonymous callback function according to the above quoted API should look like this ... `elem.addEventListener('changeDate', function (evt) { console.log(evt.detail.date); console.log(evt.detail.datepicker ===  datepicker); });`

Comment: Thank you!! it's working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a working example to add an event, for the Date Range picker( assuming we are using object-oriented programming ( classes ), The changeDate event must be applied to each of the input elements . Note that since I am using Date range Picker there I have two inputs , but in your case you may be using just a single input for Datepicker.

this.dateRangePicker = new DateRangePicker( this.dateRangeEl, {
clearBtn: true,
} );

```
      this.dateRangeInputEls = this.querySelectorAll( 'input' );

    if ( this.dateRangeInputEls.length ) {
        this.dateRangeInputEls.forEach( ( dateInputEl ) => {
            dateInputEl.addEventListener( 'changeDate', ( event ) => this.handleDatesSelection( event ) );
        } );
    }
    
        handleDatesSelection( event ) {
    const dateEl = event.target;
    this.selectedDates = this.dateRangePicker.getDates( 'yyyy-mm-dd' );
    const startDate = this.selectedDates?.[ 0 ] ?? '';
    const endDate = this.selectedDates?.[ 1 ] ?? '';

    console.log( 'this.selectedDates', this.selectedDates );
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).